# Latex arrow hook up

Tags: symbols

Can anyone tell me how to write `\hookuparrow` in Latex?
I know that writing `$\hookrightarrow$` gives us the arrow to the right but for up and down arrows it is not true, maybe I need some package ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Surely [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol) could help you.

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\hookuparrow}{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\hookrightarrow$}}}
\newcommand{\hookdownarrow}{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\hookrightarrow$}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$a\hookrightarrow b$

\noindent
$a\hookuparrow b$

\noindent
$a\hookdownarrow b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the center (origin) of rotation using either `t` or `b` in `\rotatebox[origin=c]` as per your needs.

If the hook is wanted on the other side, as noted by Barabara Beeton, You may either reflect the arrow:

```
\newcommand{\hookuparrow}{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=t]{-90}{\reflectbox{$\hookrightarrow$}}}}
\newcommand{\hookdownarrow}{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=t]{90}{\reflectbox{$\hookrightarrow$}}}}
```

or use `\hookleftarrow`:

```
\newcommand{\hookuparrow}{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=t]{270}{$\hookleftarrow$}}}
\newcommand{\hookdownarrow}{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=t]{90}{$\hookleftarrow$}}}
```

Comment: if the hook is wanted on the other side for some reason, the `\hookleftarrow` can be substituted with appropriate change in direction (270 instead of 90 should do it).  i don't know what such a change might signify, and would be interested in finding out.